# How do you handle an answer that says "google it"?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

I recently downvoted an [answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900688/how-is-this-boolean-expression-evaluated) (edit: it was deleted very quickly after making this post) and wasn't sure if more action was needed.

[image]

It seems like an *attempt* to answer the question so I feel hesitant about flagging it. Although it doesn't answer the question for several reasons: it offers no explanation, uses imprecise terminology and says "google it!" I also don't think it addresses the question at all (unlike [Tony D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26900747/3920237)). After reading [How to deal with “Have you tried Google?” comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76195/how-to-deal-with-have-you-tried-google-comments) and Bill the Lizard 's answer to [Embrace the non-Googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5292/231078) it appears to me that "google it!" is frowned upon, although those questions deal with comments, not answers.

The OP's comment is even more confusing since I have no idea what he means by "... is right though, ..."

Should I just edit out "Google it!" and move on?

Comment: I don't know about the editing, I think you will find mixed feelings on that here. Personally, I would just down-vote it - which is definitely a reasonable action. An NAA flag would be [questionable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag) given that the question itself must be considered to determine this one (e.g. it would be an arguably valid answer if the question were "What is this called?").

Comment: if the answer looks fine without "google it", it is fine

Comment: Yes, edit it out. If the answer's crap afterwards then flag/Downvote/delete etc. If it's not crap, there's now a useful (non-rude) answer.

Comment: Wait. Why does your screenshot show completely different answer from the one you have linked?

Comment: @nicael:  The answer has since been deleted, and is visible to 10K+ users.  That said, there's no difference between the screenshot and the post.

Comment: if it says google it, then there's no choice but to upvote it.
(sorry i couldn't resist :D ).

Comment: @Makoto If it was deleted, the link would open the question, but it links *directly* to the answer and it becomes highlighted, as you see. So just wrong link?

Comment: @nicael My mistake. I'm not a 10k user so I can't fix it.

Comment: google it google meister

Comment: Can we please ban this user?

Comment: That's not how you solve problems in real life and it shouldn't be the first thing you to on the internet @self. Banning obviously has it's place but you cause a lot less resentment if you give people a chance first. For instance, your overly harsh comment about banning means that you should be banned. Fair?

Comment: I almost think it borders on a link only answer without the actual link. I would see it as akin to a user posting a `Google it` link that looked like: https://www.google.com/search?q=inline-if-statement&rct=j

Comment: You should google it

Comment: @ViruZX Yes, one should Google their questions before posting it, but to post an answer on a Stack Exchange that is so vague that it contains nothing more than "Google it." is just dumb. Writing it in a comment is somewhat more acceptable but even so, not very useful.

Comment: In this specific case _it wasn't_ an attempt to answer the question "How is this boolean expression evaluated?" It is incorrect in the context of C++ and googling it will therefore not help neither with understanding the conditional operator nor how the specific question was evaluated.

Answer (score 23):

One of the main points in the site, from my POV, is to give an answer that clarifies and solves the problems presented in the question without the need to look for more info somewhere else.

We are here to help each other with our problems by "creating a collection of high-quality questions and answers of lasting value" (thanks to @Deduplicator for the phrase), not to explain a framework, technology or the like. That's what blogs and videos are for, and there are usually more than enough of those.

I don't think it's wrong to *put a link* to another site but only if it is for expanding the information provided in the answer.

This means, I'll explain the solution in my answer (either by explaining it myself and/or quoting another web site) and then put a link to a useful resource for **additional** info/tutorial/example.

An answer that just says "Look for XXX in google" is not an answer at all. *At most, it should be a comment*.

So, to answer your question, what I do is:

- If the answer solves the problem, I can edit the "look for ... in google" part out of it.
- If it is like the one in your example, I may just downvote it and leave a comment explaining why I did so, just like you did.
- If it is just the "look..." part, then flag it as "Not an answer".

Comment: Though keep in mind that "we are here to help each other" is strictly to be seen in the context of "creating a collection of high-quality questions and answers of lasting value". Not by providing free pizza or some such.

Comment: @Deduplicator That's exactly what I meant with the phrase :) I added it (and your name) to my answer aswell.

Comment: That user needs to be banned for life - The user that answered the question with "Google it"

Comment: The worst part, is often I see phrases like google it, on years old answers that are now the first post on google when I am searching the problem.

I feel like slapping the user through the screen saying "Where do you think I just came from."

Comment: @Deduplicator What's wrong with free pizza?

Comment: @PhilLello: Nothing, and reserve me some pieces. (Just an allusion to another meta-discussion about what SO is for, and a comment I really liked.)

Comment: It's funny how one can literally copy-paste a post title to google and it shows you the correct answer as first result. How to deal with such questions? SO is not a mechanical turk for Google assistants, is it?